# Why are no updates shown for Ubuntu 10.10 any more?

Tags: 10.10, apt

I haven't updated my server (10.10) for quite a while.

I updated package information with `sudo apt-get update` and then ran `sudo apt-get upgrade` as usual, which resulted in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat) end-of-life reached on April 10, 2012

as here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

see the announcement here https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2012-April/000158.html

Even if you are sure , system is not upto date as far as **last** updates is concerned , cross-check the packages Version [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/)

Last update was made on 5th April as [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/maverick/)

Comment: Seems like I updated somewhere in may and these where the last updates.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.10 [**has reached its EOL**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) in April 10, 2012, there are no more updates for it. If you want to sue more recent software and up to date packages you need to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because support for most Ubuntu releases lasts 18 months. (Except for LTS releases, e.g. 10.04 and 12.04, where support is for three/five years.)

Support for Ubuntu 10.10, which was released in October 2010, [ended on the 10th April 2012](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2012-April/000158.html). This means that the update servers for 10.10 are no longer online.

Comment: I wouldn't say the update servers are no longer online, just no longer maintained. They're still online at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/. I frequently end up adding those to the sources.list when I need to add packages to an old system to assist in migrating its content to another system running a new version.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable the updates for 10.04, that's your only option at the moment. You can achieve that by editing your sources.list as explained below:

- Pack that sources.list up first (important!): `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
- Then use replace to replace the word 'maverick' for the word 'lucid'
- Save the file
- Run `sudo apt-get update` again

You might get an error about some link extras.ubuntu.com, hash them out from the sources.list file and run again.